# What does it mean for a corrupted photo to appear on my album?

Tags: photos

So I decided to clear out some photo for storage and I pasted by this photo here, but it was corrupted:

[image: corrupted photo]

The photo was actually took yesterday (12/25/18) but today I open to find it like this. I don't know how the image got to be like that, but I'm worried that it can be a virus or it can damage the phone in another way.

Comment: A "virus" is unlikely (no such thing on Android). But it might be faulty storage (or trouble with the camera app). Are other files on the same storage corrupted as well? Is it internal storage, or the external SD card?

Comment: Also it happens if an image file is being downloaded from network and the connection is interrupted. Which directory contains this image? Some photo viewers and galleries also have bugs/incompatibilities for certain formats.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue too and in my case i have transferred pictures from another device to my device and *Sharing Tool* (sharing app) was buggy and it corrupted some files.

So make sure if you transferred from another device.

Or

It could be possible if you have 'Auto Backup' enabled in any cloud storage. It also makes my image looks like yours and what i did uninstalled that app but images that are affected still not recovered.